pyvista's smooth malfunctioning
~
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import pyvista as pv
    
    face = 48
    level = 0.3
   ......
    mesh = pv.CylinderStructured(radius=level, height=3,  theta_resolution=face, z_resolution=100)
    ......
    # question here
    mesh = mesh.extract_geometry().smooth(boundary_smoothing=True, feature_smoothing=False, n_iter=100, relaxation_factor=0.1, edge_angle=12)
    mesh.plot(show_edges=True)



You probably have to clean() your grid with some tolerance to fuse the touching edges of your grid, see the linked duplicate. Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.
